# Why is Varnish 4 getting slow after some time?

Tags: varnish

We've migrated Varnish from Version 3 to Version 4.0.1 (via Debian packages). Nearly the same configuration and memory setup runs flawlessly on varnish 3. However, with Varnish 4 there are large delays (2 - 10 seconds) when requesting a cached object after some time (2 - 24 hrs).

Below is a varnishstat output:

```
MAIN.uptime             167191         1.00 Child process uptime
MAIN.sess_conn         6329434        37.86 Sessions accepted
MAIN.sess_drop               0         0.00 Sessions dropped
MAIN.sess_fail               0         0.00 Session accept failures
MAIN.sess_pipe_overflow            0         0.00 Session pipe overflow
MAIN.client_req_400                0         0.00 Client requests received, subject to 400 errors
MAIN.client_req_411                0         0.00 Client requests received, subject to 411 errors
MAIN.client_req_413                0         0.00 Client requests received, subject to 413 errors
MAIN.client_req_417                0         0.00 Client requests received, subject to 417 errors
MAIN.client_req              6329449        37.86 Good Client requests received
MAIN.cache_hit               3094149        18.51 Cache hits
MAIN.cache_hitpass              6321         0.04 Cache hits for pass
MAIN.cache_miss              3083819        18.44 Cache misses
MAIN.backend_conn             108651         0.65 Backend conn. success
MAIN.backend_unhealthy             0         0.00 Backend conn. not attempted
MAIN.backend_busy                  0         0.00 Backend conn. too many
MAIN.backend_fail                  0         0.00 Backend conn. failures
MAIN.backend_reuse           3141847        18.79 Backend conn. reuses
MAIN.backend_toolate            4418         0.03 Backend conn. was closed
MAIN.backend_recycle         3146280        18.82 Backend conn. recycles
MAIN.backend_retry                25         0.00 Backend conn. retry
MAIN.fetch_head                    1         0.00 Fetch no body (HEAD)
MAIN.fetch_length            2845771        17.02 Fetch with Length
MAIN.fetch_chunked            322232         1.93 Fetch chunked
MAIN.fetch_eof                     0         0.00 Fetch EOF
MAIN.fetch_bad                     0         0.00 Fetch bad T-E
MAIN.fetch_close               60292         0.36 Fetch wanted close
MAIN.fetch_oldhttp                42         0.00 Fetch pre HTTP/1.1 closed
MAIN.fetch_zero                    0         0.00 Fetch zero len body
MAIN.fetch_1xx                     0         0.00 Fetch no body (1xx)
MAIN.fetch_204                   138         0.00 Fetch no body (204)
MAIN.fetch_304                 16221         0.10 Fetch no body (304)
MAIN.fetch_failed                 16         0.00 Fetch body failed
MAIN.pools                         2          .   Number of thread pools
MAIN.threads                     200          .   Total number of threads
MAIN.threads_limited               0         0.00 Threads hit max
MAIN.threads_created             225         0.00 Threads created
MAIN.threads_destroyed            25         0.00 Threads destoryed
MAIN.threads_failed                0         0.00 Thread creation failed
MAIN.thread_queue_len              0          .   Length of session queue
MAIN.busy_sleep                41876         0.25 Number of requests sent to sleep on busy objhdr
MAIN.busy_wakeup               41876         0.25 Number of requests woken after sleep on busy objhdr
MAIN.sess_queued                  28         0.00 Sessions queued for thread
MAIN.sess_dropped                  0         0.00 Sessions dropped for thread
MAIN.n_object                  24161          .   N struct object
MAIN.n_vampireobject               0          .   N unresurrected objects
MAIN.n_objectcore              24273          .   N struct objectcore
MAIN.n_objecthead              34049          .   N struct objecthead
MAIN.n_waitinglist               191          .   N struct waitinglist
MAIN.n_backend                     5          .   N backends
MAIN.n_expired               3063120          .   N expired objects
MAIN.n_lru_nuked                   0          .   N LRU nuked objects
MAIN.n_lru_moved             2467465          .   N LRU moved objects
MAIN.losthdr                       2         0.00 HTTP header overflows
MAIN.s_sess                  6329434        37.86 Total Sessions
MAIN.s_req                   6329449        37.86 Total Requests
MAIN.s_pipe                     5774         0.03 Total pipe
MAIN.s_pass                   145365         0.87 Total pass
MAIN.s_fetch                 3229184        19.31 Total fetch
MAIN.s_synth                     340         0.00 Total synth
MAIN.s_req_hdrbytes       3619855685     21651.02 Request header bytes
MAIN.s_req_bodybytes        38264281       228.87 Request body bytes
MAIN.s_resp_hdrbytes      1994822975     11931.40 Response header bytes
MAIN.s_resp_bodybytes    95329048038    570180.50 Reponse body bytes
MAIN.s_pipe_hdrbytes         4022681        24.06 Pipe request header bytes
MAIN.s_pipe_in            1021617212      6110.48 Piped bytes from client
MAIN.s_pipe_out            108398777       648.35 Piped bytes to client
MAIN.sess_closed             6262741        37.46 Session Closed
MAIN.sess_pipeline                 0         0.00 Session Pipeline
MAIN.sess_readahead                0         0.00 Session Read Ahead
MAIN.sess_herd                   101         0.00 Session herd
MAIN.shm_records           677928134      4054.81 SHM records
MAIN.shm_writes             60451920       361.57 SHM writes
MAIN.shm_flushes                  79         0.00 SHM flushes due to overflow
MAIN.shm_cont                  25476         0.15 SHM MTX contention
MAIN.shm_cycles                  303         0.00 SHM cycles through buffer
MAIN.sms_nreq                      0         0.00 SMS allocator requests
MAIN.sms_nobj                      0          .   SMS outstanding allocations
MAIN.sms_nbytes                    0          .   SMS outstanding bytes
MAIN.sms_balloc                    0          .   SMS bytes allocated
MAIN.sms_bfree                     0          .   SMS bytes freed
MAIN.backend_req             3244724        19.41 Backend requests made
MAIN.n_vcl                         1         0.00 N vcl total
MAIN.n_vcl_avail                   1         0.00 N vcl available
MAIN.n_vcl_discard                 0         0.00 N vcl discarded
MAIN.bans                          1          .   Count of bans
MAIN.bans_completed                1          .   Number of bans marked 'completed'
MAIN.bans_obj                      0          .   Number of bans using obj.*
MAIN.bans_req                      0          .   Number of bans using req.*
MAIN.bans_added                    1         0.00 Bans added
MAIN.bans_deleted                  0         0.00 Bans deleted
MAIN.bans_tested                   0         0.00 Bans tested against objects (lookup)
MAIN.bans_obj_killed               0         0.00 Objects killed by bans (lookup)
MAIN.bans_lurker_tested            0         0.00 Bans tested against objects (lurker)
MAIN.bans_tests_tested             0         0.00 Ban tests tested against objects (lookup)
MAIN.bans_lurker_tests_tested            0         0.00 Ban tests tested against objects (lurker)
MAIN.bans_lurker_obj_killed              0         0.00 Objects killed by bans (lurker)
MAIN.bans_dups                           0         0.00 Bans superseded by other bans
MAIN.bans_lurker_contention              0         0.00 Lurker gave way for lookup
MAIN.bans_persisted_bytes               13          .   Bytes used by the persisted ban lists
MAIN.bans_persisted_fragmentation            0          .   Extra bytes in persisted ban lists due to fragmentation
MAIN.n_purges                                0          .   Number of purge operations
MAIN.n_obj_purged                            0          .   number of purged objects
MAIN.exp_mailed                        3111388        18.61 Number of objects mailed to expiry thread
MAIN.exp_received                      3111388        18.61 Number of objects received by expiry thread
MAIN.hcb_nolock                        6184294        36.99 HCB Lookups without lock
MAIN.hcb_lock                          2826444        16.91 HCB Lookups with lock
MAIN.hcb_insert                        2826444        16.91 HCB Inserts
MAIN.esi_errors                              0         0.00 ESI parse errors (unlock)
MAIN.esi_warnings                            0         0.00 ESI parse warnings (unlock)
MAIN.vmods                                   3          .   Loaded VMODs
MAIN.n_gzip                                  0         0.00 Gzip operations
MAIN.n_gunzip                          2741291        16.40 Gunzip operations
MAIN.vsm_free                           971600          .   Free VSM space
MAIN.vsm_used                         83963008          .   Used VSM space
MAIN.vsm_cooling                             0          .   Cooling VSM space
MAIN.vsm_overflow                            0          .   Overflow VSM space
MAIN.vsm_overflowed                          0         0.00 Overflowed VSM space
MGT.uptime                              167191         1.00 Management process uptime
MGT.child_start                              1         0.00 Child process started
MGT.child_exit                               0         0.00 Child process normal exit
MGT.child_stop                               0         0.00 Child process unexpected exit
MGT.child_died                               0         0.00 Child process died (signal)
MGT.child_dump                               0         0.00 Child process core dumped
MGT.child_panic                              0         0.00 Child process panic
MEMPOOL.vbc.live                            15          .   In use
MEMPOOL.vbc.pool                            10          .   In Pool
MEMPOOL.vbc.sz_wanted                       88          .   Size requested
MEMPOOL.vbc.sz_needed                      120          .   Size allocated
MEMPOOL.vbc.allocs                      108651         0.65 Allocations
MEMPOOL.vbc.frees                       108636         0.65 Frees
MEMPOOL.vbc.recycle                     108388         0.65 Recycled from pool
MEMPOOL.vbc.timeout                      43212         0.26 Timed out from pool
MEMPOOL.vbc.toosmall                         0         0.00 Too small to recycle
MEMPOOL.vbc.surplus                          0         0.00 Too many for pool
MEMPOOL.vbc.randry                         263         0.00 Pool ran dry
MEMPOOL.busyobj.live                         0          .   In use
MEMPOOL.busyobj.pool                        10          .   In Pool
MEMPOOL.busyobj.sz_wanted                65536          .   Size requested
MEMPOOL.busyobj.sz_needed                65568          .   Size allocated
MEMPOOL.busyobj.allocs                 3250473        19.44 Allocations
MEMPOOL.busyobj.frees                  3250473        19.44 Frees
MEMPOOL.busyobj.recycle                3248273        19.43 Recycled from pool
MEMPOOL.busyobj.timeout                 101777         0.61 Timed out from pool
MEMPOOL.busyobj.toosmall                     0         0.00 Too small to recycle
MEMPOOL.busyobj.surplus                      0         0.00 Too many for pool
MEMPOOL.busyobj.randry                    2200         0.01 Pool ran dry
MEMPOOL.req0.live                            0          .   In use
MEMPOOL.req0.pool                           10          .   In Pool
MEMPOOL.req0.sz_wanted                   65536          .   Size requested
MEMPOOL.req0.sz_needed                   65568          .   Size allocated
MEMPOOL.req0.allocs                    3165016        18.93 Allocations
MEMPOOL.req0.frees                     3165016        18.93 Frees
MEMPOOL.req0.recycle                   3163145        18.92 Recycled from pool
MEMPOOL.req0.timeout                     92611         0.55 Timed out from pool
MEMPOOL.req0.toosmall                        0         0.00 Too small to recycle
MEMPOOL.req0.surplus                         0         0.00 Too many for pool
MEMPOOL.req0.randry                       1871         0.01 Pool ran dry
MEMPOOL.sess0.live                           0          .   In use
MEMPOOL.sess0.pool                          10          .   In Pool
MEMPOOL.sess0.sz_wanted                    384          .   Size requested
MEMPOOL.sess0.sz_needed                    416          .   Size allocated
MEMPOOL.sess0.allocs                   3164961        18.93 Allocations
MEMPOOL.sess0.frees                    3164961        18.93 Frees
MEMPOOL.sess0.recycle                  3162993        18.92 Recycled from pool
MEMPOOL.sess0.timeout                    92505         0.55 Timed out from pool
MEMPOOL.sess0.toosmall                       0         0.00 Too small to recycle
MEMPOOL.sess0.surplus                        0         0.00 Too many for pool
MEMPOOL.sess0.randry                      1968         0.01 Pool ran dry
MEMPOOL.req1.live                            0          .   In use
MEMPOOL.req1.pool                           10          .   In Pool
MEMPOOL.req1.sz_wanted                   65536          .   Size requested
MEMPOOL.req1.sz_needed                   65568          .   Size allocated
MEMPOOL.req1.allocs                    3164517        18.93 Allocations
MEMPOOL.req1.frees                     3164517        18.93 Frees
MEMPOOL.req1.recycle                   3162740        18.92 Recycled from pool
MEMPOOL.req1.timeout                     91596         0.55 Timed out from pool
MEMPOOL.req1.toosmall                        0         0.00 Too small to recycle
MEMPOOL.req1.surplus                         0         0.00 Too many for pool
MEMPOOL.req1.randry                       1777         0.01 Pool ran dry
MEMPOOL.sess1.live                           0          .   In use
MEMPOOL.sess1.pool                          10          .   In Pool
MEMPOOL.sess1.sz_wanted                    384          .   Size requested
MEMPOOL.sess1.sz_needed                    416          .   Size allocated
MEMPOOL.sess1.allocs                   3164473        18.93 Allocations
MEMPOOL.sess1.frees                    3164473        18.93 Frees
MEMPOOL.sess1.recycle                  3162704        18.92 Recycled from pool
MEMPOOL.sess1.timeout                    91576         0.55 Timed out from pool
MEMPOOL.sess1.toosmall                       0         0.00 Too small to recycle
MEMPOOL.sess1.surplus                        0         0.00 Too many for pool
MEMPOOL.sess1.randry                      1769         0.01 Pool ran dry
SMA.s0.c_req                           5615570        33.59 Allocator requests
SMA.s0.c_fail                                0         0.00 Allocator failures
SMA.s0.c_bytes                     71277740514    426325.22 Bytes allocated
SMA.s0.c_freed                     70585949062    422187.49 Bytes freed
SMA.s0.g_alloc                           47820          .   Allocations outstanding
SMA.s0.g_bytes                       691791452          .   Bytes outstanding
SMA.s0.g_space                      1430526372          .   Bytes available
SMA.Transient.c_req                     871408         5.21 Allocator requests
SMA.Transient.c_fail                         0         0.00 Allocator failures
SMA.Transient.c_bytes               9784649739     58523.78 Bytes allocated
SMA.Transient.c_freed               9784414099     58522.37 Bytes freed
SMA.Transient.g_alloc                      262          .   Allocations outstanding
SMA.Transient.g_bytes                   235640          .   Bytes outstanding
SMA.Transient.g_space                        0          .   Bytes available
VBE.server1(10.10.21.78,,80).vcls                               1          .   VCL references
VBE.server1(10.10.21.78,,80).happy                   18446744073709551615          .   Happy health probes
VBE.server1(10.10.21.78,,80).bereq_hdrbytes             290806044      1739.36 Request header bytes
VBE.server1(10.10.21.78,,80).bereq_bodybytes                 1690         0.01 Request body bytes
VBE.server1(10.10.21.78,,80).beresp_hdrbytes            153255326       916.65 Response header bytes
VBE.server1(10.10.21.78,,80).beresp_bodybytes          8626069868     51594.10 Response body bytes
VBE.server1(10.10.21.78,,80).pipe_hdrbytes                      0         0.00 Pipe request header bytes
VBE.server1(10.10.21.78,,80).pipe_out                           0         0.00 Piped bytes to backend
VBE.server1(10.10.21.78,,80).pipe_in                            0         0.00 Piped bytes from backend
VBE.server2(10.10.21.79,,80).vcls                               1          .   VCL references
VBE.server2(10.10.21.79,,80).happy                   18446744073709551615          .   Happy health probes
VBE.server2(10.10.21.79,,80).bereq_hdrbytes             290837520      1739.55 Request header bytes
VBE.server2(10.10.21.79,,80).bereq_bodybytes                 1140         0.01 Request body bytes
VBE.server2(10.10.21.79,,80).beresp_hdrbytes            153283230       916.82 Response header bytes
VBE.server2(10.10.21.79,,80).beresp_bodybytes          8586809601     51359.28 Response body bytes
VBE.server2(10.10.21.79,,80).pipe_hdrbytes                      0         0.00 Pipe request header bytes
VBE.server2(10.10.21.79,,80).pipe_out                           0         0.00 Piped bytes to backend
VBE.server2(10.10.21.79,,80).pipe_in                            0         0.00 Piped bytes from backend
VBE.server3(10.10.21.80,,80).vcls                               1          .   VCL references
VBE.server3(10.10.21.80,,80).happy                   18446744073709551615          .   Happy health probes
VBE.server3(10.10.21.80,,80).bereq_hdrbytes             290783134      1739.23 Request header bytes
VBE.server3(10.10.21.80,,80).bereq_bodybytes                    0         0.00 Request body bytes
VBE.server3(10.10.21.80,,80).beresp_hdrbytes            152434626       911.74 Response header bytes
VBE.server3(10.10.21.80,,80).beresp_bodybytes          8627121897     51600.40 Response body bytes
VBE.server3(10.10.21.80,,80).pipe_hdrbytes                      0         0.00 Pipe request header bytes
VBE.server3(10.10.21.80,,80).pipe_out                           0         0.00 Piped bytes to backend
VBE.server3(10.10.21.80,,80).pipe_in                            0         0.00 Piped bytes from backend
LCK.sms.creat                                                      0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.sms.destroy                                                    0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.sms.locks                                                      0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.smp.creat                                                      0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.smp.destroy                                                    0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.smp.locks                                                      0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.sma.creat                                                      2         0.00 Created locks
LCK.sma.destroy                                                    0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.sma.locks                                               12925874        77.31 Lock Operations
LCK.smf.creat                                                      0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.smf.destroy                                                    0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.smf.locks                                                      0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.hsl.creat                                                      0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.hsl.destroy                                                    0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.hsl.locks                                                      0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.hcb.creat                                                      1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.hcb.destroy                                                    0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.hcb.locks                                                5629656        33.67 Lock Operations
LCK.hcl.creat                                                      0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.hcl.destroy                                                    0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.hcl.locks                                                      0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.vcl.creat                                                      1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.vcl.destroy                                                    0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.vcl.locks                                                6577502        39.34 Lock Operations
LCK.sessmem.creat                                                  0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.sessmem.destroy                                                0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.sessmem.locks                                                  0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.sess.creat                                               6329434        37.86 Created locks
LCK.sess.destroy                                             6329434        37.86 Destroyed locks
LCK.sess.locks                                                  1847         0.01 Lock Operations
LCK.wstat.creat                                                    1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.wstat.destroy                                                  0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.wstat.locks                                             15680311        93.79 Lock Operations
LCK.herder.creat                                                   0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.herder.destroy                                                 0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.herder.locks                                                   0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.wq.creat                                                       3         0.00 Created locks
LCK.wq.destroy                                                     0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.wq.locks                                                28915924       172.95 Lock Operations
LCK.objhdr.creat                                             2826574        16.91 Created locks
LCK.objhdr.destroy                                           2792524        16.70 Destroyed locks
LCK.objhdr.locks                                            51924239       310.57 Lock Operations
LCK.exp.creat                                                      1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.exp.destroy                                                    0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.exp.locks                                               18371384       109.88 Lock Operations
LCK.lru.creat                                                      2         0.00 Created locks
LCK.lru.destroy                                                    0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.lru.locks                                               12278364        73.44 Lock Operations
LCK.cli.creat                                                      1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.cli.destroy                                                    0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.cli.locks                                                  55733         0.33 Lock Operations
LCK.ban.creat                                                      1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.ban.destroy                                                    0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.ban.locks                                                6723420        40.21 Lock Operations
LCK.vbp.creat                                                      1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.vbp.destroy                                                    0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.vbp.locks                                                 100102         0.60 Lock Operations
LCK.backend.creat                                                  5         0.00 Created locks
LCK.backend.destroy                                                0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.backend.locks                                            6618483        39.59 Lock Operations
LCK.vcapace.creat                                                  1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.vcapace.destroy                                                0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.vcapace.locks                                                  0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.nbusyobj.creat                                                 0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.nbusyobj.destroy                                               0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.nbusyobj.locks                                                 0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.busyobj.creat                                            3250473        19.44 Created locks
LCK.busyobj.destroy                                          3250473        19.44 Destroyed locks
LCK.busyobj.locks                                           25068258       149.94 Lock Operations
LCK.mempool.creat                                                  6         0.00 Created locks
LCK.mempool.destroy                                                0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.mempool.locks                                           33618855       201.08 Lock Operations
LCK.vxid.creat                                                     1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.vxid.destroy                                                   0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.vxid.locks                                                   601         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.pipestat.creat                                                 1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.pipestat.destroy                                               0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.pipestat.locks                                              5774         0.03 Lock Operations
```

I think reasons are the high count of lock operations. Could someone explain what "Lock Operations" means and how to avoid them?

Answer (score -1):

without knowing much about your setup it seems the issue is ehre

```
MAIN.backend_reuse           3141847        18.79 Backend conn. reuses
```

Also it seems your only serving about 50% of your incoming connections via varnish cache the other 50% goes to your backend where its getting a connection refused most of the time.

Comment: Hi, why could this be an issue, apart from the bad hit rate?

Comment: Where did you get "connection refused" from?

Comment: He read "refuse" where it says "reuse".

Comment: Why is backend_reuse bad?